# Removing in-game ad

Tags: steam, shogun-2-total-war

How do I remove these in-game advertisements from the menu screen of Shogun 2?

[image: in-game advertisements]

Answer (score 1):

You better don't.

The game is [VAC](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valve_Anti_Cheat) secured, any change of those files might lead to a VAC ban.

I doub't that you will be, but imho it is not worth the risk.

Comment: I doubt there is an easy way to do it either.